# Filling an array with data from dat files in python

Tags: python, arrays, binaryfiles, reshape

I have a folder that has dat files, each of which contains data that should be places on a 360 x 181 grid. How can I populate an array of that size with the data? First, the data comes out as a strip, that is, 1 x (360*181). The data needs to be reshaped and then placed into the array.

Try as I might I can not get this to work correctly. I was able to get the data to read into an array, however it seemed that it was being placed into elements psuedo-randomly, as each element did not necessarily match up with the correct placement, as I had previously found in MATLAB. I also have the data in txt format, should that make this easier.

Here is what I have so far, not much luck (very new to python):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
############################################ 
#
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
#
#############################################

level = input("Enter a level: ");
LEVEL = str(level);
MODEL = raw_input("Enter a model: ");
NX = 360;
NY = 181;
date = 201409060000;
DATE = str(date);
#############################################

FileList = [];
data = [];

for j in range(24,384,24):
         J = str(j);
         for i in range(1,51,1):
                I = str(i);
                fileName = '/Users/alexg/ECMWF_DATA/DAT_FILES/'+MODEL+'_'+LEVEL+'_h_'+I+'_FT0'+J+'_'+DATE+'.dat';
                fo = open(FileList(i), "r");
                data.append(fo);
```

Comment: please give a sample input & output

Comment: Unfortunately, VIM ate my script, which I'm in the process of re-writing at the moment.

Comment: Some comments about your coding style: always use 4 spaces for indentation, no need to use `;` to finish a line, use spaces after commas, avoid long lines ... see [pep 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also, for constructing the filename from various parameters, use something like `fileName = '/path/{}_{}_h_{}_FT0{}_{}.dat'.format(MODEL, LEVEL, I, J, DATA)`, then you even don't need to convert `I` and `J` to string by hand.